# Force Lucene (in OpenCms) to show results in a specific Locale

Tags: search, search-engine, jsp

I've a website mounted with OpenCms and it use "Lucene" as Search Engine. My website is available in two languages: Spanish (supported) and Gallegan (not supported). I've achieved my search proccess works well but results is always show in Spanish. Is it posible force Lucene to show results in a specific locale?

Answer (score 0):

When you build the search index, you could create a new Field called Language.
Use that Field to filter your search results.

**EDIT**

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.Add(new Field("Language", "GL", Field.Store.NO,
            Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS));
...

indexWriter.AddDocument(document);
```

Get top 10 documents in GL:

```
Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File("..."));
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(dir);
Query q = new TermQuery(new Term("Language", "GL"));
TopDocs hits = searcher.search(q, 10);
searcher.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

When i build the search index (in the backoffice) i have an option called "Locale" where i can specify the locale of the index. I did it and created two separate index; one with locale "es" called "index-es" and other with locale "gl" called "index-gl".

I pass different index name with the function "setIndex" whether my user is using one language or other one but don't works. Always show contents in ES locale.

Do you refer to this or I didn't understand you?